# Shell script wrapper for Docker build and run

Tags: bash, shell, wrapper, dockerfile

I have written a simple wrapper for `docker build` and `docker run` that allows me to build and run my image without having to use the `docker` command directly.

Here's the layout of my code:

```
esp8266
├── scripts
│   ├── config.sh  <- configuration
│   └── util.sh    <- utility functions
├── docker         <- docker image root
│   └── Dockerfile
├── build          <- script to build image
└── make           <- script to run image
```

And the files themselves:

**`scripts/config.sh`**

```
readonly DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME="jackwilsdon/esp8266"
readonly DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG="0.1.0"
readonly DOCKER_IMAGE_MOUNT="/mnt/data"

readonly DOCKER_LOCAL_SOURCE_DIRECTORY="docker"
readonly DOCKER_LOCAL_MOUNT_DIRECTORY="data"
```

**`scripts/util.sh`**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# Utilities for esp8266 development container scripts

# usage: print [args...]
print() {
  echo "${CURRENT_SCRIPT}: $*"
}

# usage: print_raw [args...]
print_raw() {
  echo "$*"
}

# usage: error [args...]
error() {
  print "error: $*" >&2
}

# usage: error_raw [args...]
error_raw() {
  print_raw "$*" >&2
}

# usage: check_requirements
check_requirements() {
  if [[ -z "${CURRENT_SCRIPT}" ]]; then
    error "CURRENT_SCRIPT not set"
    exit 1
  fi

  if [[ -z "${CURRENT_DIRECTORY}" ]]; then
    error "CURRENT_DIRECTORY not set"
    exit 1
  fi

  if [[ -z "${DOCKER_BINARY}" ]]; then
    error "unable to find docker (DOCKER_BINARY not set)"
    return 1
  fi
}

# usage: docker [args...]
docker() {
  "${DOCKER_BINARY}" "$@"

  local exit_code="$?"

  if [[ "${exit_code}" -ne 0 ]]; then
    error "${DOCKER_BINARY} exited with code ${exit_code}"
    return 1
  fi
}

# usage: arg_or_default arg default [new arg value]
arg_or_default() {
  if [[ -n "$1" ]]; then
    if [[ "$#" -eq 3 ]]; then
      echo "$3"
    else
      echo "$1"
    fi
  else
    echo "$2"
  fi
}
```

**`build`**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# Build esp8266 development container

readonly CURRENT_SCRIPT="$(basename -- ${BASH_SOURCE[0]})"
readonly CURRENT_DIRECTORY="$(cd "$(dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)"
readonly DOCKER_BINARY="$(command -v docker)"

source "${CURRENT_DIRECTORY}/scripts/config.sh"
source "${CURRENT_DIRECTORY}/scripts/util.sh"

# usage: usage [printer]
usage() {
  local printer="$(arg_or_default "$1" 'print_raw')"

  "${printer}" "usage: ${CURRENT_SCRIPT} [-h] [TAG]"
}

# usage: full_usage [printer]
full_usage() {
  local printer="$(arg_or_default "$1" 'print_raw')"

  usage "${printer}"
  "${printer}"
  "${printer}" 'Build tool for esp8266 development container'
  "${printer}"
  "${printer}" 'arguments:'
  "${printer}" '  -h                    show this help message and exit'
  "${printer}" '  TAG                   the tag of the image to build'
}


# usage: build_image [tag]
build_image() {
  # Generate image name
  local name="${DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME}:$(arg_or_default "$1" \
                                                    "${DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG}")"

  print "building image ${name}"

  # Run docker with the provided arguments
  docker build -t "${name}" \
                  "${CURRENT_DIRECTORY}/${DOCKER_LOCAL_SOURCE_DIRECTORY}"
}

# usage: main [-h] [-d DATA_DIRECTORY] [-t TAG] [ARGS...]
main() {
  check_requirements "$@" || exit 1

  while getopts ':h' OPT; do
    case "${OPT}" in
      h)
        full_usage
        exit 0
        ;;
      ?)
        full_usage
        print
        error "invalid argument: ${OPTARG}"
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
  done

  shift $((OPTIND - 1))

  build_image "$@"
}

if [[ "$0" == "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" ]]; then
  main "$@"
fi
```

**`make`**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# Run esp8266 development container

readonly CURRENT_SCRIPT="$(basename -- ${BASH_SOURCE[0]})"
readonly CURRENT_DIRECTORY="$(cd "$(dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)"
readonly DOCKER_BINARY="$(command -v docker)"

source "${CURRENT_DIRECTORY}/scripts/config.sh"
source "${CURRENT_DIRECTORY}/scripts/util.sh"

# usage: usage [printer]
usage() {
  local printer="$(arg_or_default "$1" 'print_raw')"

  "${printer}" "usage: ${CURRENT_SCRIPT} [-h] [-d DATA_DIRECTORY] [-t TAG]" \
               "[ARGS...]"
}

# usage: full_usage [printer]
full_usage() {
  local printer="$(arg_or_default "$1" 'print_raw')"

  usage "${printer}"
  "${printer}"
  "${printer}" 'Make tool for esp8266 development container'
  "${printer}"
  "${printer}" 'arguments:'
  "${printer}" '  -h                    show this help message and exit'
  "${printer}" '  -d DATA_DIRECTORY     mount point for /mnt/data inside the'
  "${printer}" '                        container'
  "${printer}" '  -t TAG                the tag of the image to run'
  "${printer}" '  ARGS...               the command to run in the container'
}


# usage: run_image [data_directory] [tag] [args...]
run_image() {
  local arguments=(run --rm --interactive --tty --entrypoint /sbin/my_init)

  # Generate volume and image names
  local volume="$(arg_or_default "$1" \
               "${CURRENT_DIRECTORY}/${DOCKER_LOCAL_MOUNT_DIRECTORY}")"
  local name="${DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME}:$(arg_or_default "$2" \
                                                    "${DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG}")"

  # Add volume and name to arguments
  arguments+=(-v "${volume}:/mnt/data" ${name})

  # Remove the first two arguments from the argument list
  shift 2

  # Run docker with the provided arguments
  docker "${arguments[@]}" -- "$@"
}

# usage: main [-h] [-d DATA_DIRECTORY] [-t TAG] [ARGS...]
main() {
  check_requirements "$@" || exit 1

  local docker_volume=''
  local docker_image_tag=''

  while getopts ':hd:t:' OPT; do
    case "${OPT}" in
      h)
        full_usage
        exit 0
        ;;
      d)
        docker_volume="${OPTARG}"
        ;;
      t)
        docker_image_tag="${OPTARG}"
        ;;
      ?)
        full_usage error_raw
        error_raw
        error "invalid argument: ${OPTARG}"
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
  done

  shift $((OPTIND - 1))

  run_image "${docker_volume}" "${docker_image_tag}" "$@"
}

if [[ "$0" == "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" ]]; then
  main "$@"
fi
```

This image is primarily designed for development and ease of use, which is why I have created these shell scripts.

Here's some examples of how to use the scripts:

```
$ ./build -h
usage: build [-h] [TAG]

Build tool for esp8266 development container

arguments:
  -h                    show this help message and exit
  TAG                   the tag of the image to build
```

```
$ ./build example_tag
build: building image jackwilsdon/esp8266:example_tag
Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.584 kB
Step 1 : FROM phusion/baseimage:latest
 ---> c39664f3d4e5
Step 2 : MAINTAINER Jack Wilsdon <jack.wilsdon@gmail.com>
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4ec300220c6c
...
Step 7 : VOLUME /mnt/data
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f9f8a21a0d16
Successfully built f9f8a21a0d16
```

```
$ ./make -h
usage: make [-h] [-d DATA_DIRECTORY] [-t TAG] [ARGS...]

Make tool for esp8266 development container

arguments:
  -h                    show this help message and exit
  -d DATA_DIRECTORY     mount point for /mnt/data inside the
                        container
  -t TAG                the tag of the image to run
  ARGS...               the command to run in the container
```

```
$ ./make whoami
*** Running /etc/my_init.d/00_regen_ssh_host_keys.sh...
*** Running /etc/rc.local...
*** Booting runit daemon...
*** Runit started as PID 9
*** Running whoami...
root
*** whoami exited with status 0.
*** Shutting down runit daemon (PID 9)...
*** Killing all processes...
```

I'm rather new to shell scripting, however I'd like to ensure my scripts are as robust as possible, is there anything I can do to improve their robustness?

Comment: Overloading the meaning of `make` might come back and bite you one day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking very good. Honestly I only have nitpicks.

---

The purpose of the 3rd argument of `arg_or_default` is unclear.
From the comment in the code I don't understand it,
and it's not used by any of the scripts.
Either explain it better in the comment, or drop it,
since you're not using it anyway.

---

The `==` operator in `[[` is for pattern matching.
When you don't need to match a pattern but a literal string,
as in `[[ "$0" == "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" ]]`,
then you can replace it with a single `=`.

---

You don't need to double-quote the `$?` variable, it's always safe.

You don't need to quote string literals like `print_raw`.

You don't need the single-quote pairs when setting a variable to empty as in `docker_volume=''`, you can write simply `docker_volume=`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I didn't know you could omit the quotes for empty variables, cool!

Answer (score 2):

This is excellent. My only suggestion would be to replace:

```
readonly CURRENT_SCRIPT="$(basename -- ${BASH_SOURCE[0]})"
```

with:

```
readonly CURRENT_SCRIPT="$(basename -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")"
```

to avoid `basename` misbehaving if the script name contains a whitespace.